# how to retrieve a XML from HttpRequest in Server

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to modify [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore-nio/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/NHttpServer.java) code, which is an asynchronous server written in java using apache httpcomponents

My client code is something like this...

```
HttpPost httpPost= new HttpPost("http://localhost:9090");
HttpEntity se= new StringEntity(XMLSTRING);
httpPost.setEntity(se);
```

My server handle is something like this

```
     public void handle(
            final HttpRequest request,
            final HttpAsyncExchange httpexchange,
            final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
        HttpResponse response = httpexchange.getResponse();
        handleInternal(request, response, context);
        httpexchange.submitResponse(new BasicAsyncResponseProducer(response));
    }

private void handleInternal(
            final HttpRequest request,
            final HttpResponse response,
            final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException { need to get xml from response}
```

Any suggestions, pointer or hints on how to go about this is welcome.

--edit--

Well after much searching found one solution

```
HttpEntity entity1 = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)request).getEntity();
        String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity1);
```

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to go about it.